# Adapting hist3 in Matlab to output xx yy zz

Tags: matlab, histogram

I'm trying to adapt the hist3 function in matlab such that as well as producing the histogram it outputs the variables plotted but I'm not succeeding. Can anyone explain how to do this? I tried declaring xx, yy, zz as global but it still wouldn't move them in to the workspace.

I don't to get in trouble with Matlab for posting their code (which I assume is copyrighted) on the forum (which is also 300 lines long) but you can have a look in matlab with

```
open hist3
```

I added at the end of hist3

```
if nargout > 0
nn = n; %this is the last line in the code

global x1 %I added these 
x1= xx;
global y1
y1 = yy;
global z1
z1 = zz;
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/hist3.html),

> `N = hist3(___)` returns the number of elements in X that fall in each bin. This syntax does not create a histogram.
>
> `[N,C] = hist3(___)` returns the positions of the bin centers in a 1-by-2 cell array of numeric vectors, and does not plot the histogram.

So you can get the bivariate histogram counts and bin centers by these syntax instead.

If you want to plot the histogram and get the values, just use the function twice:

```
hist3(yourData);
[N,C] = hist3(yourData);
```

---

Now if you want the 2D grids as well *(equivalent to your `x1`, `y1`)*, you can generate those using functions like `meshgrid` - [documentations](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html). Using `C{1}` and `C{2}` as input to the `meshgrid` function.

I'd really recommend *against* changing any of MATLAB's built-in functions.

Comment: Follow up question - now I can get the data I wanted, I want to take a mean of a couple of histograms then replot the histogram - so how do I make a histogram from N?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. `N` is the height of histogram bars, do you want to plot the histogram of `N`? In that case you can simply use `hist(N)`. I also don't know what you mean by "taking the mean of a couple of histograms". Please clarify.

Comment: Ok, I have several histograms of different experiments. I have used hist3 to get the distribution of the data for each test. Now I have N for each test, so I can find the mean N for all tests. Which leaves me with X,Y (from C{1} & C{2}) and Z = mean N. How do I reconstruct the histogram now I've taken the mean? 

* I think it might be best if I ask another question - give me a moment to ask it  - I'll comment a link.

Comment: New question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63076959/reconstructing-a-histogram-in-matlab